# Corrupt ZIP files using PHP & PCLZip

Tags: php, zip, compression, archive

I'm having some issues, I'm using PCLZip to create an archive. I don't get any errors, the zip file is created, but when I go to view it, the archive is empty and on my windows machine I get an error "The Compressed (zipped) folder "local directory zip file") is invalid. I have the following code:

```
$dir = '../downloads/liability/';
$archive = new PclZip($dir.'archive.zip');
$v_list = $archive->create($dir);
    if ($v_list == 0) {
        die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
    }
```

My directory structure is:

```
-admin
  --liabilityDev.php (where the above code resides)
  --index.php
  --commission.php
-downloads
  --liability
    ---one.pdf
    ---two.pdf
```

The end result is that in the liability folder, there is a file called archive.zip which contains the 2 pdf's but I get the invalid error.
If I don't have the directory variable, I archive index.php and commission.php and that works fine. It leads me to believe it may be a permission issue, but I'm running on fumes now. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if(extension_loaded('zip')){
 $zip = new ZipArchive();
 if($zip->open('../downloads/liability/archive.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===TRUE){
   $zip->addFile('path of any normal file to be add into zip');  
 }
 $zip->close();
}
```

I think, this will fullfill your need. Before implementing this code, please check first that, zip extension is already loaded or not.